# compiling nested jars using ant

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath

I have a Java project,`Parent`, which depends on a `Child` sub-project (in the form of a JAR).  This `Child` depends on library `A` and `B` and those get bundled in with `Child`.  `Parent` uses `A`and `B` as well (meaning direct calls, not indirect through `Child`.  I want to be able to include `A` and `B` JARs only once in my project.

When I am compiling `Parent`, I get a `cannot find symbol` when it references libraries `A` and `B`.  I believe this is because `Child` is on the compile time path, but for some reason the libraries within it are not.

I am using ant as my building tool - is there anything special I should be doing in my javac tags for nested jars?  Right now in `Parent`'s build.xml I have:

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac 
        srcdir="${src.dir}"
        destdir="${build.dir}"
        includeantruntime="false"
        classpathref="build.classpath">
    </javac>
</target>

<path id="build.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

This should be including all of the jars present in my lib folder, but it doesn't seem to include all of the jars within jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem stemmed from the fact that Java cannot natively reference jars inside of jars.  You'll need to use something like http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/ to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `A.jar` and `B.jar` are thirdparty libraries, rather than outputs of your own build.

In that case, one way to resolve this would be to create a project or directory for thirdparty libraries which can then be used by your multiple projects. In the environment you have described, your `Child` project will bundle them into its own build output and the `Parent` project will use them directly on its classpath.

Lets say that your create your `thirdparty` project at the same level in the file system as your other projects:

```
  thirdparty
    lib
      A.jar
      B.jar
  Parent
    build.xml
    src
  Child
    build.xml
    src
```

In your build files, you can define the location of the thirdparty project:

```
<property name="thirdparty" value="../thirdparty"/>
```

and reference it in paths:

```
<include name="${thirdparty}/lib/A.jar"/>
<include name="${thirdparty}/lib/B.jar"/>
```